# Hide ion input validation border in IONIC-3

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

Im used ionic 3 , i want to know how to remove validation border color, red and green .

[image: Example line]
 I tried to removed,  using this css

`.item-inner {
border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
}`

its not work, that solution is removed every focus line , any one know how to remove only validation color

Comment: do you want this for all form fields or a particular one?

Comment: @SurajRao Sir , I want to do remove all of validation line red and green

Comment: the answer isnt working?

Comment: @SurajRao ,its work for me , thanks for your solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want for all input fields:

You can override the following scss variables which are set by default for android material design:

```
$text-input-highlight-color-valid:transparent;
$text-input-highlight-color-invalid:transparent;
```

For individual elements you can have a custom class in your corresponding scss class and then set border-bottom for ng-valid, ng-invalid classes with border-bottom-color.

```
.my-input.ng-invalid{
   border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.my-input.ng-valid{
   border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I think you'd also need to target `.my-input.input-has-focus` to remove the blue line when setting the focus on the input (I know the question only mentions the red and green lines, but just in case).

Comment: @sebaferreras OP seemed to be specifically asking about validation lines.So didnt target that..otherwise agreed

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks sir, its work for me

Comment: Not working for ionic v4