# Issue with ion-input border bottom

Tags: ionic3

I have form fields and I am validating those fields. If validation failed I am showing a border at the bottom with a red line but it doesn't fully cover the ion-input.

```
  <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Vorname</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="vorname" type="text" [class.invalid]="registerform.controls.vorname.touched && registerform.controls.vorname.errors"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>


 .invalid{
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.71);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide ion input validation border in IONIC-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800465/hide-ion-input-validation-border-in-ionic-3)

Comment: basically the border class belongs to `ion-item` not `ion-input`...

Comment: sorry i could not understand i do not want to hide input validation because i have set custom border for class for invalid field and i ahve to keep red line but its not fully cover. please explain some more

Comment: arent you getting a default bottom border? This is in android platform right?

Comment: this is not default border bottom initially do not have any problem when ever user skip this field i am showing error message with red line and both platform showing same.

Comment: yes.. as duplicate answer suggests add a class to your _ion-item_ dynamically in case of invalid and just change the border-bottom-color.. what you are seeing on the corner is the _ion-item_ border which is parent of _ion-input_.. So it comes out

Comment: I have added invalid class to ion-item but this time right side no problem but left side exceeds the border. if you see here same problem http://setiasunny.blogspot.de/2017/09/ionic-3-login-screen-and-validations.html

Comment: is it possible to apply border none to the ion-item whenever triggers invalid class.

Comment: sure.. I guess you can set class dynamically to both when invalid

Comment: i have applied border-bottom:none inside my invalid class but it is not triggering. i have tried to apply  `ion-item { border-bottom-color:red}` but its not trigger

Comment: ion-item is a component.. use a custom class .. check the duplicate

Comment: @Urock please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to override in variable.scss android material design. Here i paste following code:

```
$text-input-highlight-color-valid:#fff;
$text-input-highlight-color-invalid:#fff;
```

**And also edit in `.scss`**

```
  .invalid{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.71);
  }

  .item-md.item-block .item-inner {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    border-bottom: #fff !important;
  }
```

Then all is ok

Comment: Still same problem.

Comment: Now check @Urock

Comment: No luck @Utpaul

Comment: @Urock now check and give me feedback

Comment: you are awesome it works fine thank you. i have one more issue with my ios that i want to aply linear gradient to the ion-content but it apply for android but not ios here what i tried `background: linear-gradient(360deg, rgba(135, 135, 135, 0) 0%, #878787 5%) !important`  you can see for more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749805/fade-bottom-text-while-scroll-to-down-with-linear-gradient/49750052#49750052

Comment: It works ios also i have changed from background to background-image but i can not achieve what i want exactly please see above stack question. thank you.

Comment: What question i see ??

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749805/fade-bottom-text-while-scroll-to-down-with-linear-gradient/49750052#49750052